# I setup a tailwind css on my html project but id does not work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

[This is folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npmbh.png)

This is the code in my tailwind.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

[This is the output it show the background color does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zevh9.png)

First I will run npm init in order to add package.json file and then i will install tailwind using the command npm i -D tailwindcss and then follow all the steps but it does configure it what i have to do now the output is

Answer (score 0):

What command did you try to build the output.css? In your case, that should be

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css
```

Also I'd recommend importing your stylesheet like this:

```
<link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
```

Make sure that you also have this in your input.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Yes I linked a wrong css file it should be ./output.css what you are suggesting thanks man